# Bluetooth devices disconnects in 3-4 sec after connect to linux computer with bluetooth adpter

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I want to connect to the linux computer with bluetooth adapter, however after connection connected device automatically disconnects after about 3 sec.

Here is some output from `journalctl -u bluetooth`:

```
Sep 08 13:47:30 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device 6C:40:08:93:F2:A3 connected eir_len 15
Sep 08 13:47:31 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:new_link_key_callback() hci0 new key for 6C:40:08:93:F2:A3 type 4 pin_len 0 store_hint 1
Sep 08 13:47:31 router bluetoothd[436]: src/device.c:device_set_bonded()
Sep 08 13:47:31 router bluetoothd[436]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x00
Sep 08 13:47:31 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device 6C:40:08:93:F2:A3 disconnected, reason 2
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 2
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr 6C:40:08:93:F2:A3 type 0 status 0xe
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x0e
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 14
Sep 08 13:47:35 router bluetoothd[436]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
```

I've tried to connect from several devices (two macbook's computer, one windows computer, iphone and android phone) and two bluetooth adapters installed in linux computer (intel 7260 wifi/bluetooth adapter and TP-Link UB400 usb bluetooth adapter).

What should I do to understand why connected devices disconnects?

kernel version: 4.9.0-11-686-pae

debian version: 9.10

bluez version: 5.43-2

Comment: Sorry to come up with such a trivial suggestion after almost 5 years but since this was the only relevant (and unanswered) result after I spent like an hour debugging the same problem: have you tried turning it off and on again? ;) My sound system would drop the connection with the same log messages, and in the end it turned out it was a problem with the device. Soft-off wouldn't fix it, only disconnecting from power.